# how to have dynamic method parameters

Tags: java, reflection

Lets say i have a method

`public abstract void doMath(Holder h);`

But I want the user to be able to *adjust* the class being passed in. Like such

`public abstract void doMath(ClassOfPersonalChoice h);`

How would I go about doing that.

Thank you for your time and effort.

PS: The class being passed contains a bunch of variables.
ie.

```
class ClassofPersonalChoice{
    double hue = 0;
int R = 240;
int G = 10;
int B = 180;
}
```

Comment: What should you do with the object that are passed to the methode?

Comment: Why can't you use `interface MyDoMathInterface`? If you can provide more data on what you are trying to achieve - you will  probably get better answers...

Comment: the object being passed in is contains a bunch of static variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you say

```
public abstract void doMath(Object h);
```

then the user can implement whatever he wants.

Advanced idea: use generics/type parameters:

```
public abstract class MathClass<T> {

   public abstract void doMath(T holder);

}
```

---

```
public class IntegerMathClass extends MathClass<ClassOfPersonalChoice> {

    @Override
    public void doMath(ClassOfPersonalChoice holder) {
      // do something with the value
    }

 }
```

Comment: I was just hoping to remove the issue of casting it later

Comment: The advances example avoids casting!

Comment: can u please explain what the purpose of the class MathClass<T> is?

Comment: That is *your* class that declares the abstract method. You didn't tell us its name.

Comment: what if I want to call that method from MathClass??How do i do that

Comment: It is `abstract`, like you've shown us, there is no implementation to call. subclasses implement the logic.

Answer (score 2):

If you declare the argument to be of type `Object`, you'd be able to pass anything. But you won't be able to do anything with it, because you don't know what type it is. That's the way statically-typed languages work.

Ideally, you should declare the argument to be of type `SomeInterface`, and all objects that you pass should be instances of classes implementing that interface. That way you will know what operations you can do on the objects, but you won't need to know their exact classes.

Comment: regarding *anything*, even an `int`? You should explicitly mention it doesn't fit for primitives...

Comment: but an `int` is not an `Integer`, and it will be autoboxed only for java5+ [which is a reasonable assumption]

Comment: which is the default assumption, since Java 5 is almost 10 years old :)